# Memory leak in VueJS 3 when updating component state

Tags: vue.js, memory-leaks, vuejs3

I'm experiencing a memory leak in VueJS 3. In my app there are constant updates from WebSocket, and app state objects are replaced by these updates. Old objects don't get garbage collected it seems.

I was able to reproduce the similar issue with this simple component:

```html
<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue'

const state = reactive({data: {}})

updateData(0)

function updateData(count) {
  state.data = {str: `Iteration ${count}`}

  setTimeout(() => updateData(count + 1), 10)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ state.data.str }}</div>
</template>
```

The memory usage grows and never stops...

**UPDATE**

There is memory leak even if the value, not the object is updated like this:

```js
function updateData(count) {
  state.data.str = `Iteration ${count}`

  setTimeout(() => updateData(count + 1), 10)
}
```

And only if state modification is completely removed the memory gets garbage collected correctly:

```js
function updateData(count) {
  setTimeout(() => updateData(count + 1), 10)
}
```

Comment: I think that you are falling in an infinite re-render sequence, due to the fact that updateData(0) is called at every re-render; it means that calling updateData(0) will always be executed. 
To avoid this, try putting the updateData(0) inside the onMounted() hook

Comment: Not sure but that may be because your proxy is still in use. Not sure that it can be garbage collected if you use the `state` variable every 10ms.

Comment: Right, it also looks like you have a recursive function here. Surprising that your app don't even crash or notify you of such thing.

Comment: @ElieAsmar that is not correct: I checked in debugger, and it is called only once for each number as expected

Comment: @kissu the state proxy is still in use, but state.data previous object should be GC'd when the value is reassigned. Also, the call is not recursive: updateData is being called by setTimeout, not by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turned out, the issue is caused by Vue Dev tools. Disabling them resolves the memory leak. More info: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/7408

Comment: Not coming from the fact that it's dev mode?

Comment: @kissu no, only related with vue dev tools browser extension.

Comment: Please mark your question as accepted.

Comment: After pulling out all my hair and buying a gun to kill myself, I decided to do one last search of the entire Internet and ended up here. Unbelievable, days and days of struggling, all because of a stvuepid extension! I had fixed the production bug but wasn't aware of it 'cause of this. Thank you, man! <3